# x11vnc does not start

Tags: xorg

Groovy Gorilla

I created a systemd service to start the x11vnc server but can't start even manually:

/usr/bin/x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess -forever -loop -noxdamage -repeat -rfbauth /home/brad/.vnc/passwd -rfbport 5900 -shared

```
 --- x11vnc loop: 1 ---

 --- x11vnc loop: waiting for: 43774

10/04/2021 12:54:55 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbauth
10/04/2021 12:54:55 passing arg to libvncserver: /home/brad/.vnc/passwd
10/04/2021 12:54:55 passing arg to libvncserver: -rfbport
10/04/2021 12:54:55 passing arg to libvncserver: 5900
10/04/2021 12:54:55 x11vnc version: 0.9.16 lastmod: 2019-01-05  pid: 43774
xauth:  file /root/.Xauthority does not exist
10/04/2021 12:54:56 -auth guess: failed for display=':0'
10/04/2021 12:54:56 -auth guess: since we are root, retrying with FD_XDM=1
10/04/2021 12:54:56 -auth guess: failed for display=':0'

 --- x11vnc loop: sleeping 2000 ms ---


 --- x11vnc loop: 2 ---
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your session must be started with X11, not wayland. The default setting is wayland in 20.10 if I'm not mistaken. But `root/.Xauthority does not exist`is strange. That file should be in your homeDir

Comment: my /etc/gdm3/custom.conf is "WaylandEnable=false"

Comment: Could you explain, why xauth is searching `.Xauthority` in /root? This file belongs to a user and should be in his home dir.